# How about the performance by using date or int in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with 20million docs. The index have 4 fields like this:

```
id 
title 
type 
created_time
```

I query this index and sort by `created_time`. And here is my question:

What's the difference by using `created_time` as date or timestamp? Since there isn't timestamp in ES, I use int to describe `created_time`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There are many advantages of using a [`date` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) for `created_time` instead of an integer:

1. you'll be able to make powerful [`date_histogram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) and [`date_range`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html) aggregations on that field
2. you'll be able to properly chart your documents on the Kibana timeline
3. you'll be able to use [date math in index names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html?q=date%20math) if you ever want/need to create daily/weekly/monthly indices
4. you'll be able to use [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) in [`range` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html?q=range%20query#ranges-on-dates)
5. you'll be able to use powerful groovy date math in scripts (query, aggregation and/or sorting)

Note, however, that since date are stored as long, you can still specify your `created_time` field as a `date` field, but send it as a long (= milliseconds since the epoch) or as an integer (= seconds since the epoch) timestamp and the field will still be considered as a date and benefit from all the goodies I enumerated above.

Comment: The created_time is not used in the cases you described above. The created_time only used for sort and for display. I can format it in application. I just worry about the performance of date type used for sort. Since date is stored as long, I am wonderfing there is not any difference in performance between date type and int. Am I right?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about int vs long, especially with only 20Mio documents

Comment: My mistake. It's 200Mio docs. I will try date type. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's always best to try and figure out, as there's no one-size-fits-all approach. It always depends on many factors, such as the RAM, CPU, HDD, etc of your hardware.